# Apply ESLint rules only to some files by pattern in IDEA

Tags: javascript, node.js, intellij-idea, eslint

My NodeJS project has the following structure:

```
project
|
|- client
|  |
|  |- .eslintrc.yml
|  | ...
|
|- server
...
```

Both `client` and `server` folders contain JS code.

For code linting I use eslint with the following config:

```
extends: ../node_modules/eslint-config-airbnb/.eslintrc
rules:
  import/no-commonjs:
    - error
env:
  browser: true
```

I use Intellij IDEA's integration with ESLint for the **real-time** linting. The problem is that IDEA checks all the files in the project, while I want it to only check files from the `client` folder.

Comment: .eslintignore should help.

Comment: @YamanJain you suggest ignoring _every folder in the project_ except `client`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 options here:

1. add `server/*` to [.eslintignore](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#eslintignore)

or

2. set up ESLint inspection to work for the desired scope only:

   - in **Settings | Appearance & Behavior | Scopes**, create a new scope with `server` excluded (or just `client` included recursively)
   - in **Settings | Editor | Inspections | JavaScript | Code quality tools**, choose this scope for **ESLint** inspection (in screenshot below, `sub` is a name of custom scope):

[image]